# Cannot resolve Derby 10.5.3.0 dependancies with Maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, derby

I'm trying to build my client application to include Derby 10.5.3.0 in a maven build.  My pom.xml dependancy is :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
  <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
  <version>10.5.3.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I get this error during the build:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project DERBY:DerbyDemo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.5.3.0 (compile)]

Other versions of Derby build fine.  I wanted to use 10.5.3.0 in the build to stay in sync with the version of the server, which is the Oracle Download of Java DB 10.5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

For reference sake, at post time version 10.9.1.0 works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.9.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

I just picked the latest version from [the Derby site](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

Answer (score 0):

That's a fairly old version of Derby. Not all versions of Derby are stored in the master Maven repositories. Can you use a newer version?

Comment: Yes I can, in fact I can resolve the dependency using version 10.5.3.0_1 in the pom.  It works, just trying to keep client and server in sync.  We use Netbeans 7.0 to configure Oracle's Java DB, and the latest JavaDB download from Oracle is 10.5.3.0.  Netbeans struggled with the embedded driver with one of the later Apache Derby versions (10.8.1.2 I believe) I tried.